# Why this is not updating Information

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

Why this code is not update information?

HTML Form:

```
<form>
<lable> ID# :</lable>
<input id= "ID" name= "ID" type= "text">

<p>
    <label>Select field to Edit</label>
    <select name="change">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="fname">First Name</option>
    <option value="lname">Last Name</option>
    <option value="email">Email</option>
    <option value="city">City</option>
    <option value="zip">Zip</option>
</select>
<lable> Enter the value to be replaced </label>
<input id = "replace" name = "replace" type = "text">
</p>

<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
```

PHP Code for updating information from database:

```
  <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "root";

    $conn = mysql_connect($servername,$username,$password);
    if(!$conn)
    { 
      die('Error!' . mysqli_error()); 
    }
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM users';
    mysql_select_db('mitsdatabase');

    $retval = mysql_query($sql, $conn);

    if(! $retval) 
    {
      die('Could not get data:' . mysql_error());
    }

    echo "<table width='300' cellpadding='5' border='1'>";
    echo "<tr> <td>ID#</td> <td>FirstName</td> <td>LastName</td> <td> Email </td> <td> City </td> <td> State </td> <td> Zip </td> </tr>";



    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval,MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {

      echo "<tr> <td>{$row['ID']}</td> . <td>{$row['fname']}</td> . <td>{$row['lname']}</td> . <td>{$row['email']}</td> . <td>{$row['city']}</td> . <td>{$row['state']} </td>. <td>{$row['zip']}</td>";
     }
    echo "</table>";
    $db_id = $_POST['ID'];
    $db_select = $_POST['change'];
    $db_replace= $_POST['replace'];

    echo " Do you want to edit any entry?";

    if(!_POST['submit'])
    {
        echo " ";
    }
    else{
        mysqli_query("UPDATE users SET db_select='$db_replace' WHERE ID = $db_id ");
    }
    mysql_close($conn);
  ?>
```

I want to update informate selected from select field but somehow it is not doing any thing. Can someone help me what is wrong with this code.

Comment: `<lable> Enter the value to be replaced </label>` Lable instead of label ? But I doubt your problem come from here... Did you try to print your values at different steps of your code to try to see what's wrong ?

Comment: yes i tried it didn't work

Comment: how can i print $db_id value?

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)` in your php file and share the result

Comment: I PRINTED VALUE OF #db_id ,select and replace which are correct somehow the problem is with mysqli_query command

Comment: when i use mysqli_query("UPDATE users SET db_select= '.$db_replace' WHERE ID = '.$db_id' ") or die(" Error! ". mysql_error()); with die message my submit button disappears

Answer (score 2):

Is your PHP on the same page as your HTML? If not, you are not directing to your php code within the `<form>` element in your HTML.

For example, if your PHP file was called 'myphpcode.php' (and in the same folder as your HTML code) then you could direct to it using the following:

`<form method="post" action="myphpcode.php">`

Comment: It didn't work i guess somehow my $db_id, $db_select, $db_replace is not working. When i try to print there value using echo $db_id it didn't print anything.

Comment: Try putting `var_dump('test');` at the top your PHP to see if this prints. If it doesn't, then your HTML is not communicating with your PHP. If it does show, then your DB credentials must be incorrect

Comment: when i use mysqli_query("UPDATE users SET db_select= '.$db_replace' WHERE ID = '.$db_id' ") or die(" Error! ". mysql_error()); with die message my submit button disappears

Comment: I think you may have the wrong stucture for your query, try this: `mysqli_query("UPDATE users SET db_select= '".$db_replace."' WHERE ID = ".$db_id);`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to post to the same page just change `<form>` to `<form method="post" action="#">` and get variables in php like this `$nameofvar = $_POST['nameofinputfield']` . Each input field should have the name tag.
Also try to change your mysql connect to this :

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
```

and after you finished the query

```
$conn->close();
```

and the query to insert

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

and you can modify this $sql string to update or delete

Comment: how can i print value of $nameofvar using echo?

Comment: echo $nameofvar; or print_r($nameofvar);

Comment: I PRINTED VALUE OF #db_id ,select and replace which are correct, somehow the problem is with mysqli_query command.

Comment: for example you can do this :
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$id = $_POST['ID'];
$replace = $_POST['replace'];
$select = $_POST['change'];
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
$sql = "UPDATE MyGuests SET column1=".$select.", column2=".$replace."
WHERE id=".$id;
$conn->query($sql);
$conn->close();
Where you update columns and table name with your own

Comment: when i use mysqli_query("UPDATE users SET db_select= '.$db_replace' WHERE ID = '.$db_id' ") or die(" Error! ". mysql_error()); with die message my submit button disappears

Comment: Dude, copy the example i did. That works. You have errors in your code.